# Cocoapod pod only for a specified platform

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, tvos

I have an Xcode project with multiple targets. One of those targets targets the tvOS platform. My other targets make use of the 'youtube-iso-player-helper' framework, which does not support tvOS. I want to have a Cocoapod Podfile that includes the player framework only on iOS.

Here is my current Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
platform :ios, '8.0'
platform :tvos, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'SVGgh'

pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1"

xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
```

When I try to update my pods, I get the following error:

> [!] The platform of the target `Pods` (tvOS 9.0) is not compatible with `youtube-ios-player-helper (0.1.4)`, which does not support `tvos`.

Obviously, this is using the current version of Cocoapods.

So, I need to know the syntax required for my Podfile.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
target 'iOSAppTarget' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'PodForiOS'
end

target 'TVAppTarget' do
  platform :tvos, '9.0'
  pod 'PodForTV'
end
```

Comment: Xcode 8.3.3 » I added the tvOS target before doing a 'pod init', and the Podfile automatically had both targets...

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a similar problem and I've fixed it by using this pattern:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'  

def shared_pods
    pod 'SVGgh'
end

target 'myiOSTargetName' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks! 
    shared_pods
    pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1"
end

target 'mytvOSTargetName' do
    platform :tvos, '9.0'  
    use_frameworks! 
    shared_pods
end
```

I haven't tested it but I hope it helps!
Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: Actually, I just edited my answer to match what it should correctly be. I believe it is a problem with cocoa pods. Have a look at this thread https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4326#issuecomment-171713294
I am about to update cocoa pods to 1.9 beta and see if it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not just you podfile, but the creator of the pod needs to enable apple TV. You can read about it here http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.39/

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. I don't need or want the youtube helper in tvOS, but I do want it on iOS. Thus my need to have different sets of frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem, but with framework. Try to use `target` and `link_with` to install pod for specific target:

```
target :tvos, :exclusive => true do
    use_frameworks!
    link_with 'AppName'
    pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1"
end
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work. [!] Unable to find a target named `ios`

Comment: `link_with` has been deprecated in CocoaPods 1.0