# I am trying to install the `VLCKit' pod file

Tags: ios, cocoapods

> Analyzing dependencies
>       [!] The platform of the target RTMP (iOS 9.0) is not compatible with VLCKit (3.0.2), which does not support ios.

I am getting the above error while installing it. And I have tried all the deployment target (cross-checked with all ). But not getting any solution.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203319/cocoapod-pod-only-for-a-specified-platform

Answer (score 1):

Please try with [MobileVLCKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/mobileVLCKit) since it looks like you're trying to build for iOS.

VLCKit is only for macOS as written [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/VLCKit):

> VLCKit is an Objective-C wrapper for libvlc's external interface on macOS.